# Posting Comments on BlogEngine

Tags: blogs, recaptcha, blogengine.net

I don't seem to be able to post comments on my blog anymore.

The blog was put together by my predecessor at the company where I work using BlogEngine.

The error message says:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: challenge
```

I'm not sure what the cause is but I believe it has to do with the change of url of Google's recaptcha plugin. I've done some research on this and the address does seem to have changed.

Apologies if this is a bit vague, but I was wondering if anyone has experienced this issue with BlogEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're facing the same issue but I had an issue with comments being posted on my blogengine blog where when you click on submit nothing happens. After a lot of digging it was a result of having the HTTP/axd compression settings turned on in blogengine.

You could try to play around with these and see if that makes a difference.

Cheers,
D